# 2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova

I made a PhoneGap/cordova app with Sencha Touch. When I build it in newest stable XCode and using the Developer key/prov. profile, I can deploy it to my iPhone and browse the interface. But when I then submit it to apple using the deployment key, I get:

> We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

and the log contains like:

> Last Exception Backtrace:
> (0x1831e42d8 0x1949040e4 0x1831e3f5c 0x18401d480 0x18310f520 0x1880447a0 0x1880465a8 0x187eb1ec4 0x187eb10e0 0x187eaf778 0x18b8c53c8 0x18319c27c 0x18319b384 0x1831999a8 0x1830c52d4 0x187c9043c 0x187c8afac 0x10007afec 0x194f82a08)
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019509b270 0x195080000 + 111216
> 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019513916c 0x195134000 + 20844
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195012b14 0x194fb0000 + 404244
> 3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001940d1414 0x1940d0000 + 5140
> 4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001940f0b88 0x1940d0000 + 134024
> 5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001949043bc 0x1948fc000 + 33724
> 6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001940edbb0 0x1940d0000 + 121776
> 7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001940ed738 0x1940d0000 + 120632
> 8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194904290 0x1948fc000 + 33424
> 9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001830c5380 0x1830bc000 + 37760
> 10  UIKit                           0x0000000187c90438 0x187c14000 + 508984
> 11  UIKit                           0x0000000187c8afa8 0x187c14000 + 487336
> 12  lightController                 0x000000010007afe8 0x100074000 + 28648
> 13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194f82a04 0x194f80000 + 10756

with (12) being my app. I am not sure how this log may help. How can I get to the root of the problem? (As I said, deploying to my iPhone works!)

Comment: cross check the version of deployment and the version of the app apple uses to check you app.

Comment: You need to symbolicate that crash report before you can make sense of it. You need to put it in Xcode alongside the submitted binary (in the archives).

Comment: Run on every Simulator and as many real devices as you can get. Run different iOS Versions and yes, symbolicate the log.

Comment: `cordova -version` returns `5.1.1`